# Remove lines based on number of characters

Tags: r, sed, dataset

I am wondering how I can remove lines from a dataset that contain more than a certain number of characters, based on the sum of two rows.

For example, in the following data:

```
2   rs121065    0   17696224    T   C
2   rs1860485   0   17696230    T   C
2   rs237147    0   17696256    C   CGAGGCAG
2   rs1909633   0   17696365    A   G
2   rs574724    0   17696368    T   C
```

I would like to remove the third line. The issue is that the series of letters is variable, and so in other places, the data may look like this:

```
2   rs113308    0   17683654    CCTTT   C
```

or this:

```
2   rs103371    0   17667279    TG  T
```

So - basically, any line that contains more than 2 characters in the last two columns needs to be removed, and ideally my dataset will look like this:

```
2   rs121065    0   17696224    T   C
2   rs1860485   0   17696230    T   C
2   rs1909633   0   17696365    A   G
2   rs574724    0   17696368    T   C
```

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: When you say "more than 2 characters" does that mean you want to keep a row that has 2 characters in one of the columns?  i.e. do you really mean "more than 1 character?"

Comment: Remove rows containing more than 1 character before summation of the final 2 columns, or more than 2 characters after summation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An R-based solution.

Let's say the focal columns are called `seq1` and `seq2`.

Then

```
mydata <- subset(mydata,nchar(seq1)+nchar(seq2)==2)
```

or if you really want to use the last two columns,

```
nc <- ncol(mydata)
mydata <- mydata[nchar(mydata[,ncol-1])+nchar(mydata[,ncol])==2,]
```

but I find the former easier to read.

Comment: +1 maybe `with` would make the second the way more readable. Using this would avoid relying on a function intended only for interactive use.

Comment: hm.. seems need learn one more language - this is a bit cryptic for me  :)

Answer (score 4):

An `awk`-based solution:

```
$ cat foo.txt
2   rs121065    0   17696224    T   C
2   rs1860485   0   17696230    T   CG
2   rs237147    0   17696256    C   CGAGGCAG
2   rs1909633   0   17696365    A   GGG
2   rs574724    0   17696368    T   C

$ awk 'length($NF)==1 && length($(NF-1))==1' foo.txt
2   rs121065    0   17696224    T   C
2   rs574724    0   17696368    T   C
```

This only keeps lines whose last two columns contain only one character each.
Adjust the length requirement as needed, which should be self-explanatory.

Comment: Thank you! It's nice to have options.

Answer (score 1):

simple `sed` ½ liner:

```
sed '/\w\{2\}\s*\w*$/d' file
```